# normalize a matrix colwise on the GPU

Tags: c++, cuda

I try to normalize a matrix colwise on the GPU with good performance. I wrote this function:

```
__global__ void test(float * x){      // data of Matrix3Xf x
 int id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

if (id < colSize) // stay within the limits x
{
    int col = id * 3;
    float norm = 1 / norm3df(x[col], x[col + 1], x[col + 2]);

    x[col] = x[col] * norm;
    x[col + 1] = x[col + 1] * norm;
    x[col + 2] = x[col + 2] * norm;
}
```

I found the data type float3 which is in the Cg Toolkit, but it's not up to date anymore (c.f. https://developer.nvidia.com/cg-toolkit) ... any ideas how to make it faster? My environment is Visual Studio 2017 and CUDA 9.2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Providing suggestions about making something faster requires understanding how fast it is now, and you have not provided anything like enough information to know that. Can you please edit a proper [MCVE] along with your performance measurements into your question, otherwise I doubt you will get a useful answer

Answer (score -2):

this works best so far:

```
__global__ void test( float * x, int colSize )     // data of Matrix3Xf x
{      
    int id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (id < colSize) // stay within the limits of x
    {
        int col = id * 3;
        float norm = x[col] * x[col] + x[col + 1] * x[col + 1] + x[col + 2] * x[col + 2];
        norm = rsqrtf(norm);

        x[col] = x[col] * norm;
        x[col + 1] = x[col + 1] * norm;
        x[col + 2] = x[col + 2] * norm;
    }
}
```